# Asus FX502 Elantech touchpad issue

Tags: 16.04, touchpad, asus, elantech

I have an Asus FX503 gaming laptop. I installed both Ubuntu and windows side by side. However the touchpad in Ubuntu is getting stuck repeatedly. I have tried almost everything on the internet still no progress. My Ubuntu version is 16.04 LTS and kernel is 4.13.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install [kernel 4.17r6 from official Ubuntu download site](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.17-rc6/), it worked for me. You'll have some dependency problems (forgot which packs) but they can be fixed with installing missing packages manually using apt-get.
 Packages you'll need:

```
linux-headers-4.17.-XXX-_all.deb

linux-headers-4.17.-XXX-.deb

linux-headers-4.17.-XXX-generic.deb

linux-modules-4.17.-XXX-.deb
```

Install them using `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` and make sure you have latest nvidia drivers (396.XX for me). Then reboot your notebook.

Hope it helps :D